Picking Up Agent with Another Agent
I trying to create a small example model before starting on a larger more complicated model using the same techniques. I have a model where I have simulated a forklift picking up pallets and taking them to a storage location. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx6atIEHM1A. Now for some reason I have gotten the model to work, besides the fact that when a forklift picks up a pallet, the pallet disappears. I believe the pallet is disappearing 'On exit' of the exit block. I have a code in this block that changes the population of the pallet from a population in main to a population in forklifts, to maintain the link and allow the two to travel together.
Here's a picture of my process flow:
enter image description here
Here's the code used in the exit block:
agent.goToPopulation(agent.flLink.getConnectedAgent().pallets);

Here's the state chart being used for the Agent Type 'Forklift':
enter image description here
Code in Entry Action of Idle Block:
if(main.seizeForklift.size()>0){
    Pallet pallet=main.seizeForklift.get(0);
    statechart.fireEvent(pallet);
}

Code in Transition to "moveToProduct" Block:
moveTo(msg);
palletLink.connectTo(msg);
main.seizeForklift.free(msg);

Code in Entry Action of attachPallet Block:
Pallet agent=palletLink.getConnectedAgent();
main.waitForForklift.free(agent);

Code in Exit Action of attachPallet Block:
palletLink.getConnectedAgent().jumpTo(getX(),getY());

Code in Entry Action of movetoDestination Block:
moveTo(main.destination);

Code in Exit Action of attachPallet Block:
palletLink.getConnectedAgent().goToPopulation(main.pallets);
main.enter.take(palletLink.getConnectedAgent());
palletLink.disconnect();

I have created an Agent Type 'Pallet' with a population of 'pallets' in both the Main agent and Forklift agent.
Any help is appreciated.
I have tried to change the jumpTo code to other values, with no luck. I've commented out the code in the attachPallet block and the issue persists. The issue is clearly in the exit block when the population changes.

maybe in your forklift agent, your population of pallets, click on the properties "show presentation"... maybe that's why it disappears... it can aslo be that it moves to the 0,0 coordinate

Thanks for the response, Felipe. The "show presentation" option being off was my first thought as well, but it's my understanding that the presentation styles are controlled by the Agent Type. The population that I pass to uses the same Pallet Agent Type as before the handoff. As for the 0,0 coordinate, that initially what I thought the issue was, but I have link tracking on, which draws a solid line between the linked agents. Once the forklift picks up the pallet the black line disappears, suggesting to me that the pallet is indeed at 0,0 of the forklift, instead of global 0,0

i mean that video shows all the steps and it should work fine...  hard to know
